# How to read a setting with an expression from file in data factory v2?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm reading a setting from a json file with an expression, but the expression doesn't work.

The setting is outputPath -> @activity('GetSet').output.value[0].subs.outputPath

The file has the expression:

"outputPath": "/subs/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy')}/subs.json"

The result should be /subs/2018/subs.json but appear the same has written in the file. If I put the expression in the Settings directly, it works.

json of my pipeline

```
{
    "name": "subscription experience",
    "type": "ExecutePipeline",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "GetSet",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "typeProperties": {
        "pipeline": {
            "referenceName": "Client",
            "type": "PipelineReference"
        },
        "waitOnCompletion": true,
        "parameters": {
            "outputPath": "@activity('GetSet').output.value[0].subs.outputPath",
        }
    }
}
```

my file is:

```
{
  "test": "my teste"
  "subs": {
    "outputPath": "/subs/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy')}/subscriptions.json",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use concat like this:

File is:

```
{
 "test": "my teste"
"subs": {
"outputPath": "/subs/",
"outputPath2": subscriptions.json",
}
```

And in parameter put:

```
@concat(activity('GetSettings').output.value[0].subs.outputPath,formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'),activity('GetSettings').output.value[0].subs.outputPath2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the expressions must be between @{}. Try with

```
@{activity('GetSet').output.value[0].subs.outputPath}
```

And remember that the activity 'GetSet' must have finished previously for this expression to have a value, so add a condition for it if you dont have it already.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't work, 'Getset' already finished but the setting appear as string /subs/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy')}/subs.json

Comment: Its hard to give you the exact answer if you dont show your complete json, for example I don't know what subs is in your json. Try @{activity('GetSet').output.value[0].outputPath} (without subs).

Comment: I put the json in my question

Comment: yes, doesn't work because output.value[0].outputPath doesn't exist